# How to upload to S3 bucket via HTML form? ("SignatureDoesNotMatch" error)

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images to an AWS S3 bucket via an HTML form.

```
<form action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/3dphy-media-dev" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AKIAI5LGVRB427BQRRTA">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value='
    {
        "expiration": "2019-01-26T16:14:30Z",
        "conditions": [
            {"bucket": "3dphy-media-dev"},
            {"key": "${filename}"},
            {"acl": "public-read"}
        ]
    }
    '>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="wml%2FZoIYBqyCHDRSSxwxkf5EvzQ%3D">
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">-->

    File to upload to S3:
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
```

However submitting the form results in an error "SignatureDoesNotMatch" and a message "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

I checked some of the existing questions on the same topic, but their answers didn't solve the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the s3 documentation? You need to sign the upload.

Comment: I included the "signature" field. 
`<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="wml%2FZoIYBqyCHDRSSxwxkf5EvzQ%3D">`

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Comment: I used this tool to calculate the signature - http://www.dancartoon.com/projects/s3-siggenerator/
Is there any similar tool for encoding policy?

Comment: Is the policy document of the bucket different from the policy document that is to be sent via the form?

Comment: Bucket policy and upload policy documents are different things, yes, but the most apparent error in your code, above, is that the policy document is not base64-encoded *in the html form* when it should be.

Answer (score 1):

`mc` tool at https://github.com/minio/mc can be used easily for this purpose as a general purpose tool to generate this.

```
$ mc share upload --recursive --expire=12h https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/backup

$ mc share list upload
URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/backup
Expire: 11 hours 19 minutes 18 seconds
Share: curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup -F x-amz-date=20151125T052221Z -F x-amz-signature=7b13a6db1af025c2b3f1e92cd7c10100b3756c98982def74692722305419a806 -F bucket=backup -F policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMi0wMlQwNToyMjoyMS45NjJaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W1siZXEiLCIkYnVja2V0IiwiYmFja3VwIl0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCIyMDA3LU1hci0yL2JhY2t1cCJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotZGF0ZSIsIjIwMTUxMTI1VDA1MjIyMVoiXSxbImVxIiwiJHgtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSIsIkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYiXSxbImVxIiwiJHgtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiLCJBS0lBSTZTTk1VRk9WSUVGT1pKQS8yMDE1MTEyNS91cy1lYXN0LTEvczMvYXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0Il1dfQ== -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F x-amz-credential=AKIAI6SNMUFOVIEFOZJA/20151125/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request -F key=2007-Mar-2/backup<NAME> -F file=@<FILE>
```

Alternatively with json output

```
$ mc share list upload --json    
{"status":"success","url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/backup/","share":"curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup -F policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMi0wMlQwNToxNTozNC45MjlaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W1siZXEiLCIkYnVja2V0IiwiYmFja3VwIl0sWyJlcSIsIiRrZXkiLCIyMDA3LU1hci0yL2JhY2t1cC8iXSxbImVxIiwiJHgtYW16LWRhdGUiLCIyMDE1MTEyNVQwNTE1MzRaIl0sWyJlcSIsIiR4LWFtei1hbGdvcml0aG0iLCJBV1M0LUhNQUMtU0hBMjU2Il0sWyJlcSIsIiR4LWFtei1jcmVkZW50aWFsIiwiQUtJQUk2U05NVUZPVklFRk9aSkEvMjAxNTExMjUvdXMtZWFzdC0xL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJdXX0= -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F x-amz-credential=AKIAI6SNMUFOVIEFOZJA/20151125/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request -F x-amz-date=20151125T051534Z -F x-amz-signature=3523fed9cc9ffed7873411c1401d3fc2926055a88704e2d20dd49b8734a25469 -F bucket=backup -F key=2007-Mar-2/backup/ -F file=@<FILE>","timeLeft":40240153132134}
```

Additionally we also have https://github.com/minio/minio-js which works in browser which can be directly plugged in your HTML form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a look into the _minio-js_ tool. However I saw that I have to include the secret key in the script, and that is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can upload to my s3 bucket via an HTML form without revealing the secret key?

Comment: @gdebojyoti -  IN such a case you need write a upload gateway as a server side functionality which knows the secret keys generates a relevant policy and fields upon a client request. 

Your client application needs to consume this API and populate HTML form based on the results. 

The easiest is to write 'mc share upload' service and write a client to talk to this service.